# What is physical path DevExtreme Server

Tags: emulation, server, devextreme

Please explain me physycal path of server which use DevExtreme. It started like localhost: but I understand where is this path of this server in OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\DevExtreme\WebServer
```